# Clear and Replace listview items on SwipeRefresh Layout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I"m populating the listview from online using JSON. It works great...But I wanted to implement method of SwipeRefresh layout such that old data will be replace with new one in every Swipe user make.

Instead of clearing old data with new one, Everytime on SwipeRefresh new data is added at the bottom of old data.

I also set notifysetAdapter; but it doesn't seems to work.

Here is my code

```html
mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void run() {

                                             mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                             mExampleList.clear();
                                             mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                             parseJSON();
                                         }
                                     }
            );


        }
    }


    private void parseJSON() {
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String videoTitle = hit.getString("title");
                                String link = hit.getString("link");
                           //     String notes = hit.getString("notes");
                          //      String question = hit.getString("question");
//                                String imageUrl = hit.getString("webformatURL");
//                                int likeCount = hit.getInt("likes");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(videoTitle,link));
                                mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

I need help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Use setOnRefreshListener**

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                     parseJSON();
                    // just on refresh call parseJSON method
                }
            });
```

Clear data in parseJSON method before add new data, and set notifyDataSetChanged out for loop.

```
private void parseJSON() {
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        try {

                            mExampleList.clear();

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String videoTitle = hit.getString("title");
                                String link = hit.getString("link");
                           //     String notes = hit.getString("notes");
                          //      String question = hit.getString("question");
//                                String imageUrl = hit.getString("webformatURL");
//                                int likeCount = hit.getInt("likes");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(videoTitle,link));
                            }

                                mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help..but when I implement your suggestion then only spinner is loading for infinite and content is not showing anything..so I reverse back to my original and now content is showing but on refresh..instead of replacing with new items..it is adding them on bottom.